# Hall's theorem proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you tell me the proof using augmenting paths of Hall's theorem.(In a bipartite graph, the vertices of the smaller set can be paired one-to-one with the vertices of the other set, if and only if every subgroup (of vertices) of the smaller set have at least as many neighbours in the other set as the number of vertices it (the subgroup) contains).

Comment: What does augmenting paths mean ?

Comment: Have you looked at the proof on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem)?